# C++ read from file and know if stream is string or numeric

Tags: c++, ifstream

I've a file like this

```
A 2 3 4 6
B 10 1 2 6
```

and when I read it I need to check if I read a character or a number. But I've no idea how...

```
    string fileName = "/Users/Fry/Desktop/file/file/file.txt";
    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open(fileName);
    char output[1000];

    if (myReadFile.is_open())
    {
        while (!myReadFile.eof())
        {
            myReadFile >> output;
            cout << output << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Read it into a string, then check the characters that are in the string.

Comment: Have a definition of the file format (Eg: A line is a string followed by numbers) and read accordingly.

Comment: And don't loop with `while ( !file.eof() )`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard C function `std::isdigit` declared in header `<cctype>` that to check whether the first character (or each character) of the read string is a digit and if so then apply C++ function `std::stoi`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

//...

std::string fileName = "/Users/Fry/Desktop/file/file/file.txt";
std::ifstream myReadFile( fileName );

std::string data;

while ( myReadFile >> data )
{
    if ( std::isdigit( data[0] ) )
    {
        std::cout << "It is number " << std::stoi( data ) << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "It is string " << data << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the file string by string, and check whether each small string is a number or not. Something like:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>
...
std::string tmp;
while (myReadFile >> tmp){
    // you got a string...
    if (is_number(tmp)){
        // it's a number
    }
    else{
        // it's not a number 
    }
}
```

To check whether a string is a number or not, you can use the following function, which is be able to handle multiple-char number like `10` or non-numbers like `123abc45`.

```
bool is_number(const std::string& s){
    return !s.empty() && s.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos;
}
```

Comment: Your use of `std::isdigit` is undefined behavior, at least if plain `char` is signed.

Comment: @JamesKanze Fixed to use `find_first_not_of` instead.

Comment: Which is far less expressive and more error prone that `isdigit`.  You just have to use `isdigit` correctly: if you have a `char`, cast it to `unsigned char` first.  (If you're using it in a lambda, the simplest solution is to declare the lambda to take a `unsigned char`, and let the implicit conversion do the rest.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Why is `find_first_not_of` far more error prone than `isdigit`?

Comment: Because you can easily mistype and omit a character in the list.  If the specification says test for a digit, then use `isdigit`.  (If the specification gives a list of characters, or specifies something for which there is no ready-made function, then of course, using a list of characters might be more appropriate.  Although in that case, I'd probably use `std::find_first_of` and compare the resulting iterator.)

Answer (score 1):

Include `<cctype>` and use `isdigit()` and `isalpha()` to check the characters read.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's relevant in this case; it looks to me like
you have a very fixed format, and can know exactly whether you
should expect a letter or a number.  But otherwise, you can
always peek ahead:

```
myFile >> std::skipws;      //  Since we're going to use unformatted input
if ( std::isalpha( myFile.peek() ) ) {
    //  It's a letter, extract it into a char or a string
} else {
    //  It's (hopefully) a number, extract it into an int
}
```

`std::istream::peek` does *not* extract the character, so it is
still there for the normal formatted extractors.  And it returns
an `int` (not a `char`) in the correct range for the functions
in `<cctype>`, so you don't have to worry about the undefined
behavior that results when calling them with a `char`.

Also, you shouldn't be using the results of `>>` before checking
to see that it succeeded, and you shouldn't use `eof()` as
a condition for a loop.